# How do I find what number is 12h06f?

Tags: binary, verilog, bit

I've found such numbers time and time again in verilog and digital logic exercises, but I don't know how I'm supposed to know what number this is or how to write it as 12'b in verilog code.

Can someone explain them to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number referred to in the post is called a literal constant or a number literal or just a literal.
There is a tutorial document with examples that is a good reference on the subject.

The document can be found here:
[/verilog_number_literals](https://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/%7Etraylor/ece474/beamer_lectures/verilog_number_literals.pdf)

The first page looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Presumably it's a 12-bit value in hexadecimal notation. Since one hexadecimal digit encodes 4 bits, there are 3 hexadecimal digits:

- hexadecimal `0` corresponds to 4 bits `0000`
- hexadecimal `6` corresponds to 4 bits `0110`
- hexadecimal `f` corresponds to 4 bits `1111`

So the same value in binary notation is `000001101111`.

In Verilog you can write

```
12'h06f
```

or

```
12'b000001101111
```

Where `12'` means "12 bits", `h` means "hexadecimal" and `b` means "binary".

Comment: I kinda get it now, but does that f have any purpose? I guess the 0 is for the 5 first 0s, the 6 is for the six 1s, but the f?

Comment: The f at the end of the literal is the hex character f, which is binary 1111, or decimal 15.